# Issue overriding tostring

Tags: java, overriding, tostring

I want to override the `Ship` class's `toString` method within the `CargoShip` class's `toString` method, so that the console will not print the year that the ship was built.  I've tried doing this, but it still prints the year.  I'm not sure if I'm coding the override incorrectly or if the problem has to do with the way the method is being called in the `ShipDemo` class.

Ship class:

```
public class Ship {
    public String shipName;
    public String yearBuilt;

    public Ship() {
    }

    public Ship(String name, String year) {
        shipName = name;
        yearBuilt = year;
    }

    public void setShipName(String name) {
        shipName = name;
    }

    public void setYearBuilt(String year) {
        yearBuilt = year;
    }

    public String getShipName() {
        return shipName;
    }

    public String getYearBuilt() {
        return yearBuilt;
    }

    public String toString() {
        //return toString() + " Name: " + shipName
        //+ "\n Year Built: " + yearBuilt;
        String str;
        str = " Name: " + shipName + "\n Year Built: " + yearBuilt;

        return str;
    }
}
```

CargoShip class:

```
public class CargoShip extends Ship {
    public int capacity;

    public CargoShip() {
    }

    public CargoShip(int maxCap, String name, String year) {
        super(name, year);
        capacity = maxCap;
    }

    public int getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    public void setCapacity(int cap) {
        cap = capacity;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + " Name: " + getShipName()
                + " Tonnage Capacity: " + getCapacity();
    }
}
```

ShipDemo class:

```
public class ShipDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Array Reference
        Ship[] shiptest = new Ship[3];

        // Elements in array set to ship type
        shiptest[0] = new Ship();
        shiptest[1] = new CargoShip();
        shiptest[2] = new CruiseShip();

        // Ship 1
        shiptest[0].setShipName("Manitou ");
        shiptest[0].setYearBuilt("1936 ");

        // Ship 2 ; Cargoship
        shiptest[1] = new CargoShip(13632, "SS Edmund Fitzgerald", "1958");

        // Ship 3 ; Cruiseship
        shiptest[2] = new CruiseShip(2620, "RMS Queen Mary 2", "2004");

        // loop to print out all ship info
        for (int i = 0; i < shiptest.length; i++) {
            // Output
            System.out.println("Ship " + i + " " + shiptest[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But, you included the body of `Ship`s version of toString, in your `CargoShip` implementation. It's working exactly as you coded it.

Comment: How so? Year isn't included.

Comment: Because you called `super.toString()`, which will invoke the `toString` method on the **superclass** of `CargoShip`, which happens to be ... `Ship`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `CargoShip` you have the following:

```
public String toString()
{       
    return super.toString() + " Name: " + getShipName() + " Tonnage Capacity: "      + 
    getCapacity();    
}
```

By calling `super.toString()` you are effectively calling the parent class `toString()` method, which includes a print of the year. You should remove that method call and change your returned String to include only the information you want to show.

Overriding a parent method means providing a method with the same name, argument list, return type, and visibility with a possibly different implementation (method body). You don't need to call `super` to make it considered overriding.

You might want to have something like this in `CargoShip`:

```
public String toString()
{       
    return " Name: " + getShipName() + " Tonnage Capacity: " + getCapacity();    
}
```

Comment: My directions say that I need a toString method that overrides the toString method in the base class

Comment: You are already doing that by defining your own `toString()` method in `CargoShip` which extends `Ship`. You don't need to call the parent one to override it. Simply having a method with the same method definition is overriding.

Comment: If I just call toString from CargoShip without super then I should get a run error.

Comment: If I run it without super I get this error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError"

Comment: That is because you are still calling `toString()` recursively, which causes an infinite loop and makes java run out of memory. Take out that method call completely. Look at my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I guess I was having a difficult time seeing what is considered an override.